# Display owner of a post in django admin list display

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

My model is like this :

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    sub_choice = ((1, 'English'), (2, 'Math'),
                  (3, 'Physics'), (4, 'Chemistry'))
    subject = models.IntegerField(choices=sub_choice, default=1, max_length=50)
    hours = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Time spent in hours', default=0)
```

My admin.py looks like this :

```
class ActivityAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('subject', 'hours')

admin.site.register(Activity, ActivityAdmin)
```

In my list display,I also want the First name of the user who created a certain activty.How do I do this without explicitly asking the creator of the activity to put their name in the form.Is there any way to get this information using a custom function from the User model ?

Comment: There is no relationship between `Activity` and `User`. How could you know who created which activity?

Comment: only a user with staff status in the admin can create an activity..for instance the admin logs have clear entries as to which user created what entry..all i want is to show who created a certain activity directly in the list display without have a user fill up that field ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use User model.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Activity(models.Model):
        sub_choice = ((1, 'English'), (2, 'Math'),
                      (3, 'Physics'), (4, 'Chemistry'))
        subject = models.IntegerField(choices=sub_choice, default=1, max_length=50)
        hours = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Time spent in hours', default=0)
        owner = models.ForeignKeyField(User)
```

admin.py

```
    class ActivityAdmin(ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('subject', 'hours', 'owner')
        exclude = ['owner']

        def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
            """
            Given a model instance save it to the database.
            """
            obj.owner = request.user
            obj.save()

admin.site.register(Activity, ActivityAdmin)
```

Comment: @wolendranh..this does not fix my issue..the owner field shows up in the activity model in the form of a drop down with the list of users allowing a user to choose anyone as the owner..what i really want is to prohibit that and display the owner field in the list display solely on the basis on the user who logged in and created the activity

Comment: @Amistad When you will save your instance of Activity it will have 1 user that will be taken from for example request.user. And only one user will be displayed for this Activity.

Comment: yes..i think request.user is what i want..however..i do not see that in your answer..how does that work with your answer

Comment: @Amistad how should this Activity added? Using form on UI or using Admin?

Comment: @Amistad check update. You will be able to rewrite save_model method and assign request.user to owner field.

Comment: @wolendranh..you have been really patient with me and i apologise for bugging you here..i think i am close but not there yet..the owner is a foreign key in the activity model and that allows anyone to change that field..what i want is for the owner field in the list display to get automatically updated with the user's first name when a model is saved..without allowing anyone else to modify it..

Comment: one more thing..if i make further changes to the model and save it again..the owner changes to numbers like 1,2 etc..would you know why that is happening..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65220/discussion-between-wolendranh-and-amistad).